# Autobahn websocket

Tags: python, websocket, autobahn, autobahnws

I'm evaluating and building a simple websocket server with [autobahn websocket](http://autobahn.ws/python/)

Has anyone used subclass **WrappingWebSocketServerProtocol**, are there any examples of using this implementation? What is the benefit over the WebSocketServerProtocol and what submethods to override/implement

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutobahnPython allows you to run any application protocol that builds on a stream-based transport protocol (like Telnet, IMAP, VNC, ..) *over* WebSocket. For this kind of wrapping, you would use the `WrappingWebSocketServerProtocol` and related classes.

AutobahnPython also allows to run WebSocket over any stream-based transport protocol/facility (like Unix domain sockets, pipes, serial, ..). For this you would use **Endpoints**: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_endpoints

Now, both of above are covering special use cases, and if you want to do a "normal" WebSocket app, you would just use the `WebSocketServerProtocol` and related classes.

Answer (score 0):

Found some answers to the following list of examples, if someone is interested:

https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/wrapping